# Media Library and Featured Image Issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-4.5.2

I just downloaded a new version of WordPress 4.5.2 and started developing a theme but when I transferred it to the live I cannot upload images on the Post's featured thumbnail same as well on the Media Library.

When I try to upload an image on the Post's featured thumbnail I always got this error:

[image]

I have changed the file permission to 777 on /wp-content/uploads/, switch themes and disabled plugins but it still not working.

Any ideas from you guys would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a more specific error message in the console? Or could you try it with a very, very small image? I had a similar problem with big images.

Comment: Check if any error found in console, while uploading image.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109117/wordpress-professional-help maybe someone can help you there.

Answer (score 0):

There can be more then 1 reason for this issue.

1. Check your file size and check if that is too much for memory to process or not
2. In recent updates many themes has been broken. You can switch to default theme for sometime and after clearing cache check if the problem is resolved.
3. Permission issue you have already tried. (Suggestion: Use 755 instead of 777 for security)
4. Still if your issue persist add define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); to your wp-config.php file and open your console. If there is any server side error you will get it directly on screen and in case of ajax in console.